# Valums fileuploader in mvc framework not working in ie8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

im using my own php mvc framework and been incorporating Valums fileuploader.
It works in FF but in IE8 (the only ie browser tested) i get a 404 error when the form is submitted.

From the console in IE i get this:

> LOG: [uploader] iframe loaded
>   LOG: [uploader] converting iframe's innerHTML to JSON
>   LOG: [uploader] innerHTML = 404

This is the Javascript i use to call Valums uploader:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Setup the ajax indicator

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({

        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        // url of the server-side upload script, should be on the same domain
        action: '/mofo/annonce/upload',
        //Only one image
        multiple: false,
        // additional data to send, name-value pairs
        params: {},

        // validation    
        // ex. ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'] or []
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'],        
        // each file size limit in bytes
        // this option isn't supported in all browsers
        sizeLimit: 10485760, // max size 10MB in bytes   
        minSizeLimit: 0, // min size

        // set to true to output server response to console
        debug: true,

        // events         
        // you can return false to abort submit
        onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
            $('#error').empty().hide();
            $('#message').empty().append('<img src="http://localhost/mofo/images/loading.gif"> Uploader billed.').css({'color':'#000', 'font-weight':'normal'}).show();

        },
        onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total){

        },
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            if (responseJSON.success) {
                $('#message').empty().append(responseJSON.message).css({'color':'#000', 'font-weight':'normal'}).show();
                $('#thumb ul').append('<li><img src="http://localhost/mofo/' + responseJSON.thumbnail + '" /></li>');

            } else {
                $('#message').empty().append(responseJSON.error).css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'}).show();
            }
        },
        onCancel: function(id, fileName){},

        messages: {
            // error messages, see qq.FileUploaderBasic for content   
            typeError: "Filen: {file} er en ikke tilladt filtype. Kun {extensions} er tilladt.",
            sizeError: "Filen: {file} er for stor, maksimum størrelsen er {sizeLimit}.",
            minSizeError: "Filen: {file} er for lille, minimum file størrelse er {minSizeLimit}.",
            emptyError: "Filen: {file} er tom, vælg en anden fil.",
            onLeave: "Filerne er igang med upload, hvis du stopper nu bliver filerne ikke uploadet."          
        },
        showMessage: function(message){ 
            $('#message').empty().append(message).css({'color':'red', 'font-weight':'bold'}).show();         
        }

    });

});
```

I modified Valums JS so its sending the file parameter like this:

```
var queryString = this._options.action + '/' + params['qqfile'];
```

Hope somebody can figure out why IE is giving me a 404 error..

Comment: In IE that plugin uses an iframe, where you edited that queryString line, is it used in both the iframe and xhr request?

Answer (score 0):

A 404 indicates that a resource wasn't fount. Check that your action path is correct.
Also if you want to pass the file name to the server, you don't need to modify the source code. Just add it to the params option in the onSubmit handler.

```
onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
    this.params.fileName = fileName;
}
```

Then just retrieve it on the server side like any other parameter.